# Using trigger to rollback update

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a trigger that will rollback an update or delete based on whether a value is present in a field.
The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_CheckValidation_Observation]
ON [dbo].[tbl_observation]
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM deleted as d
        WHERE d.verificationDate IS NOT NULL)

BEGIN
RAISERROR ('Cannot change data that has been validated', 16, 1);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
RETURN
END;

GO
```

Currently, the verfifiedDate is null for all records

If I run this:

```
IF EXISTS (select * from tbl_observation
            where verificationDate is not null)
    BEGIN
        print 'Verification Date has values'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        print 'Verification Date has no values'
        update tbl_observation set verificationDate = GETDATE() where water_year = 2002
    END
```

I get:

> Verification Date has no values 
>   Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_CheckValidation_Observation, Line 12 Cannot change data
>   that has been validated Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   tr_Modified_Observation, Line 6 The transaction ended in the trigger.
>   The batch has been aborted.

Am I using the deleted table incorrectly or is there another way to lock individual rows?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using an AFTER TRIGGER which is fired after the triggering action. you need to use INSTEAD of Trigger here.

Comment: And you really do not need a trigger for this simple requirement just make your `verificationDate` column `NOT NULL`able.

Comment: Thanks M.Ali, I guess I wasn't quite clear enough. verificationDate allows NULL and is NULL when a record is created. This field will get a Date-Time when the users say that the data is clean. I want to lock records that have been marked as clean. However, the trigger is blocking me from entering a value into the verificationDate field; the record I'm trying to update has this field as NULL.